# jquery removeClass not working (class or id issue?)

Tags: jquery, css, removeclass

I'm using Jquery to do pagination and basic CSS for nice navigation links. My issue is that the removeClass is not working and all my page numbers change of color permanently once clicked on, while only the current one should. Here is parts of my code that should be relevant to my problem:

```
var navigation_html = '<ul id="pagination">';
navigation_html += '<li><a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a></li>';
var current_link = 0;
while(number_of_pages > current_link){
   navigation_html += '<li><a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a></li>';
   current_link++;
}
navigation_html += '<li><a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a></li>';
navigation_html += '</ul>';

// Automatically add active class to first page
$('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active');

function go_to_page(page_num){
    var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());
    start_from = page_num * show_per_page; 
    end_on = start_from + show_per_page;  

    $('#content').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');
    $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#current_page').val(page_num);  
}

<STYLE type="text/css"> 
#pagination {list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}  
#pagination li{float:left; margin:3px;}  
#pagination li a{   display:block; padding:3px 5px; color:#fff; background-color:#44b0dd; text-decoration:none;}  
#pagination li a.active {border:1px solid #000; color:#000; background-color:#fff;}  
#pagination li a.visited {background-color:#DAD8D8; color:#777; border:1px solid #ccc;} 
</STYLE>
```

Comment: you should make a js fiddle for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rcvmQ/12/

Comment: For some reason I cannot move through the pages. But on my end (DEV website) I can.

Comment: Actually if I remove the <ul> and <li> and change my CSS for "a" only, everything works. So I guess this is coming from the syntax I use with the classes. What am I doing wrong ??